# regex for a full name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I've recently been receiving a lot of first name only entries in a form.  While maybe I should have had 2 separate first and last name fields this always seemed to me a bit much.  But I would like to try and get a full name which basically can only be determined by having at least one space.

I came up with this, but I'm wondering if someone has a better and possibly simpler solution?

```
/([a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,.'-]{2,}) ([a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,.'-]{2,})/
```

This is basically this `/([a-zA-Z,.'-]) ([a-zA-Z,.'-])/` plus unicode support.

Comment: You could try asking the users, If your site bugged me for a full name then I most likely wouldnt use it.

Comment: Well, that's true, but... it's in their best interest.  If they don't give a full name, they are less likely to get an accepted booking from the end host (which is not me).

Comment: Then give them this information.

Comment: They have it, and yet... they still leave "Bob"

Comment: @holden And if that is a issue then add a field for their last name and require it. Don't add a regular expression that imposes your idea of what a name should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd first make sure that you really do need people to give you a last name. Is that a genuine requirement? If not, I'd skip it because it adds unnecessary complication and barriers to entry. If it really IS a requirement, it probably makes sense to have separate first and last name fields in your UI so that it's explicit.

The fact that you didn't do that to begin with suggests that you might not really need the last name as much as you think you do.

To answer your original question, this expression might give you what you're looking for without the guesswork:

```
/[\w]+([\s]+[\w]+){1}+/
```

It checks that the string contains at least 2 words separated by whitespace. Like Tim Pietzcker pointed out, validating the words themselves is prone to error.

Comment: All I want to validate by regex is the same function provided by having 2 fields and this is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the names entered contain no numbers?

Comment: Try this: `/[^\d\W]+([\s]+[^\d\W]+){1}+/` The leading carrot before the character class negates it. The classes are ANDED together. So the set [^\d\W] matches characters that are not digits (\d) and not non-word characters (\W).

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9, you have access to Unicode properties (`\p{L}` is a Unicode letter). But trying to validate a name in any way (regex or not) is prone to failure because [names are not what you think they are](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Your theory that "if there's a space, there must be a last name there" is incorrect, too - think of first and middle names...

Comment: So.... does that mean I should separate it into 2 fields?  I'm not creating the yellow pages or trying to match 100% of all names Ad infinitum. I just want to stop people from entering "Bob" as a full name. People can answer incoherently on any form. I'd just like a small semblance of meaning and avoid having 2 fields if I can get by with one.  That article is not useful.

Comment: @holden: What if `Bob` *is*  that person's full name? See falsehood 20 in that link. You can impose any rule you want, and whichever rule you choose, you will p**s off somebody (See @Devin M's comment above). So then check whether `/ /` matches if it makes you happy.

Comment: Hey, it's your choice. If you want to actively discourage users from other places than America and Europe from using your site, and you don't care that `Billy Bob` will slip through your name validation scheme, then you're perfectly well entitled to do so.

Comment: If what you're saying were true (which I agree, it could be) they also couldn't use a credit card since they usually require both a first and last name to verify users and usually a home address... which again... some people are homeless.  which is both sad and neither here nor there. etc.  They also can't have a facebook account since it also requires 2 names.

Comment: And this proves what exactly?